# Apache Beam - How to associate transformed record with original?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, streaming, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am creating an Apache Beam pipeline using the Python SDK to read from PubSub and write to BigQuery. I am trying to preserve the original message from PubSub so that if there are any errors, I can write out the original record to be fixed and then reprocessed. The simplest way I have made this work is to use a tuple containing the original message and the working message:

```
(initial_message, working_message)
```

Then when I do Map transformations, I transform the working message and return the tuple back, keeping the original message intact:

```
pipeline = (pipeline
            | 'Read PubSub' >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)
            | 'Decode' >> Map(lambda record: (record, record.decode('utf-8')))
            | 'Example Transform' >> Map(lambda record: (record[0], some_transformation(record[1])))
)
```

This seems to work great until writing to BigQuery:

```
write_results = (
    pipeline
    | 'Extract working message' >> Map(lambda record: record[1])
    | 'Write to BigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery(table=table,
                                             project=project,
                                             schema=schema,
                                             create_disposition=create_disposition,
                                             write_disposition=write_disposition,
                                             insert_retry_strategy=insert_retry_strategy
)

write_results['FailedRows'] | 'Handle write failures' >> ?
```

How do I then associate the failed row with the original message?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question. Is there some way to assign identifiers to each record? For example, you can add a unique identifier to each record like so:

```
def assign_id(input_record):
  return RecordWithId(id=uuid.uuid4(),  # Generate a random unique ID for it
                      record=input_record)

def append_id(record_with_id):
  record_with_id.record['_beam_id'] = record_with_id.id

data = (pipeline
            | 'Read PubSub' >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)
            | 'AssignId' >> Map(lambda record: assign_id(record))
            | 'Decode' >> Map(lambda record: (record, RecordWithId(record.id, record.record.decode('utf-8'))))
            | 'Append Id to Row' >> Map(lambda pair: (pair[0], append_id(pair[1]))
            | 'Example Transform' >> Map(lambda record: (record[0], some_transformation(record[1])))
)

write_results = .... # Write to BQ

# And finally, you would do:

kv_failures = write_results['FailedRows'] | KeyBy(lambda row: row['_beam_id'))
kv_original = data | KeyBy(lambda row_w_id: row_w_id.id)

joined_data = (kv_failures, kv_original) | CoGroupByKey()
```

Does this make sense? You can then process `joined_data`.